# How to give links from post via facebook php api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to post links from posts descriptios as in the screenshot:

[image]

I tried lots of things with facebooks php api like this:

```
 $POST = array(
//      'description' => $smiley[$smileyid]['description'],
    'picture' => $oyun_resim,
    'name' => 'Arkadaşın ' . $oyun_adi . ' adlı oyunda size meydan okunuyor !',
    'link' => $oyun_link,
    'caption' => "Arkadaşın sana meydan okuyor !!",
    'description' => "<b>Arkadaşın bu oyunda sana meydan okuyor, ona rakip olmak için oyuna başla ve ondan fazla puan topla.</b><br />
                    {\"name\": \"OYNA !!\", \"link\": \"$oyun_link\"}",
//      'message' => "",
    'text' => 'OYUNA BAŞLA !',
    'href' => $oyun_link,
    'actions' => '{"name": "OYNA !!", "link": "' . $oyun_link . '"}',
    'cb' => '');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one url in a facebook post (link) as of now.

Here's a list of all the parameters you can use in a facebook post:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post

-Roozbeh

Comment: i took this screenshot yesterday, so it is possible to post links in posts description, i think. I tried everything on that page but it didn't help me :( .